# What to do it I found out that the same question I asked on SE has been asked on another Q&A website?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on this SE. I later found out that the same question has been asked on another Q&A website. Where shall I add a link to it? In my SE question? As a comment? I don't want to copy the content as an answer to avoid license issues, and I don't want to paraphrase it. Also, new answers might be posted on the other Q&A website. I'd prefer avoid the SE community to re-writing some information that already been written somewhere else.

Comment: I'm unsure of why you feel the need to do this; I've never seen it done on another SE site. You asked a question. You found an answer. If you feel it's share-worthy, post it as an answer. Remember, though, that link-only answers are subject to deletion.

Comment: @anongoodnurse license issues. The vast majoroty of SE websites (all other SE websites?)  are fine with people leaving a relevant link in a comment.

Comment: Then I should think the issue is moot. Answers in comments are deleted here. Stick with the other website.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I find it disrespectful toward the visitors of my question. What's the issue with leaving a link?

Comment: That's a different question. That question is more like: "I want to post *an answer* from a different website [*in my question*](http://health.stackexchange.com/posts/170/revisions) as a link. Is that acceptable?"

Comment: @anongoodnurse It a potential answer to my current meta question. Leaving the link as a comment is what all other SEs I frequent do.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It's usually fine to do that (posting the related link under the answer) and it perfectly works on every other SE websites (I'm doing that all the time), however this site unfortunately has some alienated rules (with high risk of deletion of your answers and comments) and I don't think it'll [change](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/325/114) soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have questions like this, often if you look on [the Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for Stack Exchange, you will find they have been answered.

In this case, answers from here can be posted on Quora with proper attribution, and vice versa, due to the type of licensing that both sites employ.

[Can I copy my answer in Quora to Stack Exchange sites or vice-versa?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247756/can-i-copy-my-answer-in-quora-to-stack-exchange-sites-or-vice-versa)

[Who owns the copyright to S[OFU] content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13976/who-owns-the-copyright-to-sofu-content)

Comment: The first meta post points to https://www.quora.com/How-can-material-on-Quora-be-reused-elsewhere-What-are-the-licensing-terms-What-about-in-the-case-where-a-user-has-selected-the-not-for-reproduction-option?share=1 , where you'll see some Quora answers are tagged "Not for reproduction".

Comment: Not for reproduction. The "Not for reproduction" option opts a user's answer out of the normal reuse license that Quora grants to everyone. If you're posting about an NFR answer there is not a restriction. However, if you're copying the contents of an NFR answer to somewhere else on Quora or to anywhere else on the web, the author of the answer might be able to stop you under copyright law, depending on whether your use qualifies as fair use. We don't police this; it's the same as if you wrote a blog post that included the contents of someone else's blog post.

Comment: Even the NFR designation may or may not be valid. And the first part that you conveniently skipped over: General. You can reuse all new content on Quora by publishing it anywhere on the web, as long as you link back to the original content on Quora

Comment: I skipped nothing. --> "you'll see **some** Quora answers are tagged NFR".

Answer (score 0):

You can add the link as a comment. The goal of Stack Exchange is to exchange knowledge, and if the link points to same question, it will certainly interest future readers while avoiding potential answerers from wasting their time writing some answer whose content is already present somewhere else.

Comment: Btw. Moving answers to Quora is actually a good idea, at least it won't be removed by mods, so it can help people further more. Thanks.

Comment: @kenorb - I have no problem with posting answers to Quora. The OP is proposing the opposite.

Comment: @kenorb - Actually, that is antithetical to the purpose of the site.

Comment: The purpose of SE sites is to help people provide useful timeless Q&A databases on selected topics. It's useless and disappointing if the comments & answers are constantly removed for personal/vague reasons. So I'm not surprised that people are looking for alternatives. I personally don't like Quora, but if I know that my priceless effort won't be removed from there, it's worth to try.

Comment: They are not personal and they are not vague. The rules are actually fairly clear.

Comment: If you want an example of vague rule, see http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/413/43 . Some other rules are clearer, but quite randomly applied.

Comment: I'm using SE for over 6 years now, and my answers were never removed on any of the sites without the actual possibility of discussing or improving them exempt in here. Appointing mods who're member for only 1 year without broader spectrum how things work here and without necessary experience on the other mainstream SE sites is the biggest mistake and I'm surprised and disappointed that such things happened here. And no any action were taken. The site lost too many active users already because of that.

Comment: @kenorb - All this was [discussed extensively in meta](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/a/273/169) before, and you were given every chance to improve your answers. Disingenuous statements help no-one.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Not true, because I was actually banned for that reason (for discussing my answers on meta) and I was told that meta isn't the right place to discuss my answers, despite every other SE meta sites are used for discussing the posts (and nobody is against it, only here things seems to work opposite).