# Would it be wrong to copy and paste your own awnser across sites?

Tags: discussion

This is sort of the reverse of this meta question:

[What to do it I found out that the same question I asked on SE has been asked on another Q&A website?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/449/what-to-do-it-i-found-out-that-the-same-question-i-asked-on-se-has-been-asked-on)

I feel on Bio.SE (pre-Health), I've already written an in depth answer to this Health question:

[Effect of the common cold on the immune system](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/452/effect-of-the-common-cold-on-the-immune-system)

Now this is a question that is exactly within my field of expertise so I know I could write pages on the subject.  Instead, I contained myself to this answer:

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21507/why-dont-we-develop-immunity-against-common-cold/21802#21802

Would it be appropriate to just move it over with minor edits?  I'm worried that if I start writing one again, I will only feel motivated to complete it if I go into more depth than my answer on Bio (which may already be long).

On the flip side it has attracted some pretty poor and flat wrong answers, so having a correct answer would certainly serve a lot of good.

Comment: As you can see from the question, I just linked to, it's fine. Especially if it's your own answer, like in your case, but even if it isn't (if attribution is added)

Comment: @YviDe I totally missed that one. Just completely didn't have the right search terms. I'm fine for this question to be close then

Comment: I only remembered because I answered it :-) Wanted to add an answer here, then vaguely remembered that I wrote something about copying other people's answers and found it in my history.